# Motion Detection on multiple cameras

Tags: c#, aforge

I have a 2 video sources and 2 new_Frame event handlers for each video source and I use two different motion detection variable to detect motion and this work fine but I want to do the same thing on parallel processing ( because I have a multiple core CPU )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got an answer from AForge.Net Site 
http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3184